# Functions and pointers

Tags: c

I have a couple of errors I need some help understanding.

Firstly, here is the test run of my program for 7 days.  I want to find a way for `void getDailyData( float* high, float* low, char* condition);` function to stop reading characters after the condition is met if there are anymore characters I'd like to prompt and error msg.

Secondly, my program is not respecting the conditions in `void getDailyData( float* high, float* low, char* condition);` function because right here how come the user is allowed to put in this input

```
Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny, p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:3.4 and not get flagged for it i don't understand how that could happen?

Enter an number between 1 and 14: 7
Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny, p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:15.3, 10.8, s
Today's average temperature is: 13.05
@☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:11.5, 5.0, c
Today's average temperature is: 8.25
~☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:9.9, 3.3, p
Today's average temperature is: 6.60
;☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:5.6, -0.8, p
Today's average temperature is: 2.40
;☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:3.4
Today's average temperature is: 1.30
;☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:3.4, -6.5, giraffe, elephant
ERROR! Try again!nEnter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny, p=p
recipitation)
 separated by commas:-6.5, 3.4, p
ERROR! Try again!
Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny, p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:3.4, -6.5, p
Today's average temperature is: -1.55
*☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:-1.1, -11.0. p
Today's average temperature is: -6.05
*☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
Your Seventh day average is: 3.43
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void clearscr(void);
char symbolToDraw(char condition, float averageTemperature);
int getInteger(int min, int max);
float average(float first, float second);
void getDailyData( float* high, float* low, char * condition);
void displayResult( int days, float allDaysAverage );
void draw( char c, int num );
int main(void){
    int numDays;
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float dailyHigh;
    float dailyLow;
    char conditions;
    float dailyAvg = 0;
    //title
    printf("Weather Analyzer 2.0\n");
    printf("====================\n");
    //prompt the user for a number of days
    printf("How many days of data?\n");
    //get an integer between 1 and 14
    numDays = getInteger(1,14);
    for(i = 0; i < numDays; i++){
        //get input from the user
        getDailyData(&dailyHigh, &dailyLow, &conditions);
        dailyAvg = average(dailyHigh, dailyLow);
        printf("Today's average temperature is: %.2f\n", dailyAvg);
        sum += dailyAvg;
        draw(symbolToDraw(conditions, dailyAvg), 20);
    }
    //remember, arguments are separated by commas
    //there are two arguments here...
    displayResult(numDays, (sum/numDays));
    return 0;
}
/*
This function prompts the user to enter an integer between the min and the max
If the input entered by the user is invalid, it displays an error and asks again.
It will continue asking the user until the integer the user enters falls between
min and max (inclusive).
This function returns an integer, ensured to be between min and max (inclusive)
and assumes that min <= max
*/
int getInteger(int min, int max){
    //your implementation here
         int value, keeptrying = 1, rc;
         char after;

         do {


                 printf("Enter an number between 1 and 14: ");
                 rc = scanf("%d%c", &value, &after);
                 if (rc == 0) {
                         printf("*Bad char(s)!*\n");
                         clearscr();
                 } else if (after != '\n') {
                         printf("*Trail char(s)!*\n");
                         clearscr();
                 } else if (value < min ||
                  value > max) {
                         printf("*Out of range!*\n");
                 } else
                         keeptrying = 0;
         } while (keeptrying == 1);

         return value;
}

/*
This function prompts the user to enter a day's worth of data (high temperature,
low temperature, weather condition) separated by commas, validates the input such
that the user is forced to enter a floating point number for the high, a floating
point number for the low. It ensures that the low temperature is not higher than
the high temperature and that the condition is one of: 'c', 's', or 'p'.
If the user enters invalid input, this function displays an error and asks again.
float * high: a pointer holding the address of the float to which the function
will copy the day's high temperature before returning.
float * low: a pointer holding the address of a float to which the function will
copy the day's low temperature before returning.
char* condition: a pointer holding the address of the char to which the function
will copy the day's condition before returning.
*/
void getDailyData( float* high, float* low, char* condition){

    int counter =0;

do{
    printf("Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny, p=precipitation) \n separated by commas:");
    scanf("%f, %f, %c", high, low, condition);
    if(*low > *high){
        printf("ERROR! Try again!\n");
        clearscr();
    }else if(!(*condition == 's' || *condition == 'p' || *condition == 'c')){
        printf("ERROR! Try again!\n");
        clearscr();
    }
    else counter =1;

}while(counter == 0);
}


/*
This function draws a row of characters (such as @@@@@@@ ).
char c holds the character that will be repeated
int num holds the number of times that the character will be repeated
The number of characters is controlled by the value of "num".
*/
void draw( char c, int num ){
    //your implementation here
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < num; i++){
        printf("%c", c);
        }
    }

/*
This function returns the average of the first and second floating point number.
*/
float average(float first, float second){
    //your implementation here
    float avg;
    avg = (first + second)/2;
    return avg;
}

/*
This function displays the average temperature for a period of days
(e.g. Your seven day average is: 14.3)
NOTE: it displays the int days as a word; for example, 3 as "three"
If the int days is greater than 9 (nine) it just prints the value;
for example Your 10 day average is: 12.2)
*/
void displayResult( int days, float allDaysAverage ){
    //your implementation here


    if(days == 1){
        printf("\nYour One ");
    }
        if(days == 2){
        printf("\nYour Second ");
    }
        if(days == 3){
        printf("\nYour Third ");
    }
        if(days == 4){
        printf("\nYour Forth ");
    }
        if(days == 5){
        printf("\nYour Fifth ");
    }
        if(days == 6){
        printf("\nYour Sixth ");
    }
        if(days == 7){
        printf("\nYour Seventh ");
    }
        if(days == 8){
        printf("\nYour Eigth ");
    }
        if(days == 9){
        printf("\nYour Ninth ");
    }
    if(days >= 10){
        printf("\nYour %d", days);
    }
    printf("day average is: %.2f\n", allDaysAverage);
}

/*
This function returns the correct character (@, ~, *, ;) given the current
condition and the average temperature.
NOTE: Precipitation character (* or ;) will change depending on the average
temperature.
char condition represents the current conditions
float averageTemperature represents the average daily temperature
*/
char symbolToDraw(char condition, float averageTemperature){
    //your implementation here
    char c = '~';
    char p = ';';
    char s = '@';
    char l = '*';

    if(averageTemperature < 0){
        p = '*';
    }

switch(condition){
case 's':
    printf("%c", s);
    break;
case 'p':
    printf("%c", p);
    break;
case 'c':
    printf("%c", c );
    break;
default:
break;
}



}

void clearscr(void){
     while (getchar() != '\n');  // empty statement intentional
}
```

Comment: "my program is not respecting the conditions...how come the user is allowed to put in this input". Because you are not checking the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The three variables are within the scope of `main` function and passed to the `getDailyData` function as pointers. That means that the values are preserved as long as the program execution is withing the scope of `main` function.

Look here:

```
;☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:5.6, -0.8, p
Today's average temperature is: 2.40
;☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺Enter today's high, low, and condition (c=cloudy, s=sunny,
p=precipitation)
 separated by commas:3.4
Today's average temperature is: 1.30
```

First entry: high is 5.6 and low is -0.8 (and p), so the average is 2.4

Second entry: high is 3.4 and low is **still** -0.8 (and **still** p), so the average is 1.3

One solution could be to reset the values for those variables before each new loop and add a condition to check whether all values are set or not.

Comment: OHHHH!!!, and im trying to reset the value and im having troubles i did this too check the values and reset outside of the loop but printf("high and low: %f, %f\n", *high, *low);
    if(*high != 0 && *low != 0){
    *high = 0;
    *low = 0;
    }

Comment: I would reset the pointers to `null`, I think it is more useful. Because `0` is a valid value in the temperature range. You won't be able to distinguish `0` as a valid temperature value and `0` as a reset value.

Comment: ooo what you're saying makes complete sense but, i dont know why im getting an error when trying to set it to null, incompatible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'void *'|

Comment: Assign like that: `high=null;` not `*high=null;`. high is the memory address of the value, *high is the value, remember that.

Comment: the program crashed :( I did this outside of the do while in the function high=NULL; and low=NULL;